# Inertial quantities in 3D physics

Tags: physics, 3d

I'm writing a little 3D physics engine and everything is peachy except that to have constraints behave correctly, I'm having to artificially scale up the inertia tensors. Worse--the amount that I have to do so seems to vary from constraint to constraint.

I'm implementing constraints according to [Erin Catto's sequential impulses paper](http://box2d.org/files/GDC2005/IterativeDynamics.pdf). It does make sense to me that it's trickier to get things to behave well rotationally via discrete time impulses, but not sure what sort of approach to take to improve performance that isn't so hand-wavy; e.g. would satisfying the constraints at the acceleration level in addition help?

Open to any advice, even if it's that there's potentially something fundamentally wrong with my implementation or that I'm being too prissy about not wanting hacky solutions, etc.

Comment: This question will have better longevity if you can briefly summarise the main points of the approach you're using — just in case the link you're citing ever becomes unavailable. This has the side benefit of making your question more searchable for users having issues with the same technique ("this paper" isn't much of a keyword to go by...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels a bit silly answering since I wasn't really close to descriptive enough, having assumed there was some large-scale misunderstanding I had. But for completeness--and for anyone else who happens to make the same, ridiculous mistake I made and happens to stumble upon this--the issue was that I wasn't respecting delta time in my orientation update. So I'd update position by some small step in time, and take an entire second's step with orientation. The explosions I was seeing were compounded by the fact that the canonical quaternion update only "works" for small rotations.

As I looked into the issue, I found [this presentation](http://box2d.org/files/GDC2013/Strunk_Oliver_Stop_My_Constraints_From_Blowing_Up.pdf) by Oliver Strunk from Havok, which mentions comfortably inflating your inertia tensors a small amount with no noticeable artifacting.